# Transformations of a left-handed gauge field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, effective-field-theory

In a set of lectures I'm watching on Effective Field Theory the professor introduces a spurion vector field, $\ell_\mu$. He then says that we take it to transform as a "left handed gauge field" and writes,
\begin{equation} 
\ell ^\mu \rightarrow L (x) \ell ^\mu L ^\dagger (x) + i \left(\partial _\mu  L (x) \right) L ^\dagger (x) 
\end{equation} 
where $L (x)$ is the transformation matrix. I've never encountered a left-handed gauge field and I would have naively only included the first part, $L \ell L^\dagger$. How did he get this transformation law?

Though the question is self contained, for more context feel free to take a look at my [lecture notes](http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/~ajd268/Notes.html) under Effective Field Theory (pg 53).

Comment: Are you sure that the second term is correct ? Don't you have $L(x)L^\dagger(x)=1$? I think it should be $(\partial_\mu L(x))L^\dagger(x)$. See for example eqs. 12-10 and 12-11 here: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~wit00103/ftip/Ch12.pdf

Comment: Then it seems to me that the pdf file I linked answer your question: you need the second term to have a gauge invariant interaction. You can also show that the field strength is gauge invariant only if you include the second term.

Comment: Great, thanks @Adam. That helped a lot. I posted an answer based on your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gauge covariant derivative is given by
\begin{equation} 
D _\mu \psi = \partial _\mu \psi - i g W _\mu ^a t _a \psi 
\end{equation} 
rearranging gives,
\begin{equation} 
i g W  _\mu = \partial _\mu \psi - D _\mu \psi 
\end{equation} 
where we write $W_\mu \equiv W_\mu^a t _a $. Under a gauge transformation we have,
\begin{align} 
i g W _\mu \psi   & \rightarrow \partial _\mu \left( L (x) \psi \right) - L (x) D _\mu \psi \\ 
 i g W ' _\mu  L\psi  & = ( \partial _\mu L ) \psi + L \partial _\mu \psi - L D _\mu \psi \\ 
i g W ' _\mu  \psi '& =   ( \partial _\mu L ) L ^\dagger L \psi  + L W_\mu L^\dagger L \psi   \\
 i g W ' _\mu  \psi ' & = \left((\partial_\mu L ) L ^\dagger + L W _\mu L ^\dagger \right) \psi'
\end{align} 
which implies that a gauge field transforms as 
\begin{equation}
i g W _\mu \rightarrow  (\partial_\mu L ) L ^\dagger + L W _\mu L ^\dagger 
\end{equation}